# Ошибка при переборе. Yii.

Tags: php, yii

При переборе итем не может обратиться к тексту.
Если вызывать $posts->text; то всё нормально. В чём проблема?

foreach($posts as $item)
{
echo $item->text;
}

Comment: В понимании ООП?

Comment: Не по теме отвечаете.

Comment: при чем здесь Yii? Учите php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

распечатайте $posts через var_dump или print_r и постмотрите что там внутри. Тогда поймете в чем ошибка. Вот такой код пропишите перед foreach.

```
var_dump($posts);

//foreach($posts as $item) { echo $item->text; }
```

и посмотрите какие данные внутри $posts. Если $posts->text срабатывает нормально, значит $posts это объект.

Тогда попробуйте распечатать так

```
foreach($posts as $key => $item) { echo $posts->$key; }
```

или так

```
foreach($posts as $key => $item) { echo $item; }
```

вот мануал http://php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.iterations.php. может что интересного найдете

Comment: Не понял..

Comment: @NyaXA, обновил ответ

Comment: $posts и есть объект.
Как его перебрать foreach`ем? Или им только массивы перебирать?

Comment: @NyaXA, извините, ошибся, поправил

Comment: Тоже не особо понял.
Как тогда обращаться к свойствам?
Кстати, ссылка битая. 404.

Comment: @NyaXA, там без точки в конце http://php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.iterations.php

Comment: @NyaXA, и вот еще что. лучше средствами yii превратить ваш объект в массив и работать в foreach-e как с массивом, а не объектом. тогда все будет проще и понятнее

Comment: Окей.
При обращении к модели без указания свойств - всё нормально. Как выбрать что - то отдельно?
И как превращать в массив?